# onIncomingMessage on Sinch-rtc never gets called on receiving Sinch IM message

Tags: sinch

I am using NodeJS and Sinch-RTC (for IM feature) and I am unable to receive IM messages on my server - Meaning my onIncomingMessage is never called even though a message is sent to my username via phone. I am using the following code on my server.

```
var SinchClient = require('sinch-rtc');
var sinchClient = new SinchClient({
   applicationKey: 'MY-APP-KEY',
   capabilities: {messaging: true, calling: true},
   supportActiveConnection: true,
});
var messageClient = sinchClient.getMessageClient();

sinchClient.start({username: 'MY_USERNAME', password: 'MY_PASSWORD'}).then(function() {
   console.log('Success!');
   global_username = username;
}).fail(handleFail)
var handleFail = function() {console.log("Message Sending failed");};

var eventListener = {
   onIncomingMessage: function(message) {
       console.log( message.textBody);
   }
}
messageClient.addEventListener(eventListener);
```

When I run this program as "node sinchReceive.js" I am unable to receive any sinch message sent to MY_USERNAME. However, I can send a message to a different username and that doesn't have any problem. Please tell me what could be wrong or if I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Is that the whole file?

Comment: Well, is the sinch client actually running then? Is it run in a process that never dies?